# Sorting by relevance: How to sort a list to have matching values first?

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash, relevance

How to sort objects with lodash by filtered values?

```
// this is coming from select
var filtered_values = [99, "female"];

// this is my data
var data = [
    { name: "John Doe", age: 24, gender: "male"   },
    { name: "Jona Yap", age: 27, gender: "female" },  // matching: female
    { name: "Einstein", age: 99, gender: "male"   }   // matching: 99
];

// How to sort on this by the values
data = _.sortby(data, filtered_values);
```

I'd like to sort the list so that, since the filtered values are 99 and female, all objects having values of 99 and|or female should be on the top.

Comment: what's wrong with the question?

Comment: Please, expand your example - how *sorted* data should look like?

Comment: it should arrange it according to the filtered values passed

Answer (score 4):

If you need just to find what matches all criteria, you can use [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs#filter):

```
_.filter(data, {gender: 'male', age: 99})
```

But your requirements seem more complex. Let's write a function to assign scores to the objects and sort them by score:

```
// I use the fact that when you add booleans they get converted to numbers.
function score(x) { return (x.gender === 'female') + (x.age === 99); }
```

Or if you don't know which fields to match, you could do:

```
function score(x) { return _.includes(x, 'female') + _.includes(x, 99); }
```

Or in a generic way:

```
var query = [99, "female"];
function score(x) { 
    return _.sum(query, function(y) { return _.includes(x, y); };
}
```

And then you can use [`_.orderBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#orderBy) to sort the list by score:

```
_.orderBy(data, score, 'desc')
```

Result:

[image]